# Jpa error when trying to call saveAll() method from repository

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to make a team management crud app using spring boot and I am coming across this error when trying to populate my DB with info.

`Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.diego.backend.entity.Rower'`

And then this is the error in the console

```
Error:(53, 28) java: method saveAll in interface org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository<T,ID> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Iterable<S>
  found: java.util.List<com.diego.backend.entity.Boat>
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    lower bounds: com.diego.backend.entity.Rower,java.lang.Object
    lower bounds: com.diego.backend.entity.Boat
```

I seems like he saveAll() method in Jpa is causing me an issue. Any solution on how to solve this error/problem?

Rower Service

```
@Service
public class RowerService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RowerService.class.getName());
    private RowerRepository rowerRepository;
    private BoatRepository boatRepository;

    public RowerService(RowerRepository rowerRepository,
                        BoatRepository boatRepository) {
        this.rowerRepository = rowerRepository;
        this.boatRepository = boatRepository;
    }

    public List<Rower> findAll() {
        return rowerRepository.findAll();
    }

    public long count() {
        return rowerRepository.count();
    }

    public void delete(Rower rower) {
        rowerRepository.delete(rower);
    }

    public void save(Rower rower) {
        if (rower == null) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE,
                    "Rower is null. Are you sure you have connected your form to the application?");
            return;
        }
        rowerRepository.save(rower);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void populateTestData() {
        if (rowerRepository.count() == 0) {
            //Below line is where the error is coming from
            rowerRepository.saveAll(Stream.of("Varsity 8", "Frosh 4+", "JV 8", "Lightweight 2-").map(Boat::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        if (rowerRepository.count() == 0) {
            Random r = new Random(0);
            List<Boat> boats = boatRepository.findAll();
            rowerRepository.saveAll(
                    Stream.of("Gabrielle Patel", "Brian Robinson", "Eduardo Haugen",
                            "Koen Johansen", "Alejandro Macdonald", "Angel Karlsson", "Yahir Gustavsson", "Haiden Svensson",
                            "Emily Stewart", "Corinne Davis", "Ryann Davis", "Yurem Jackson", "Kelly Gustavsson",
                            "Eileen Walker", "Katelyn Martin", "Israel Carlsson", "Quinn Hansson", "Makena Smith",
                            "Danielle Watson", "Leland Harris", "Gunner Karlsen", "Jamar Olsson", "Lara Martin",
                            "Ann Andersson", "Remington Andersson", "Rene Carlsson", "Elvis Olsen", "Solomon Olsen",
                            "Jaydan Jackson", "Bernard Nilsen")
                            .map(name -> {
                                String[] split = name.split(" ");
                                Rower rower = new Rower();
                                rower.setFirstName(split[0]);
                                rower.setLastName(split[1]);
                                rower.setBoat(boats.get(r.nextInt(boats.size())));
                                rower.setYear(Rower.Year.values()[r.nextInt(Rower.Year.values().length)]);
                                String email = (rower.getFirstName() + "." + rower.getLastName() + "@" + rower.getBoat().getName().replaceAll("[\\s-]", "") + ".com").toLowerCase();
                                rower.setEmail(email);
                                return rower;
                            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
    }
}
```

Rower Repo

```
public interface RowerRepository extends JpaRepository<Rower, Long> {

}
```

Boat Repo

```
public interface BoatRepository extends JpaRepository<Boat, Long> {

}
```

Rower Entity

```
@Entity
public class Rower extends AbstractEntity implements Cloneable {

    public enum Year {
        Freshmen, Sophomore, Junior, Senior
    }

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName = "";

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName = "";

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String test = "";

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "boat_id")
    private Boat boat;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    private Rower.Year year;

    @Email
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String email = "";

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Year getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Year year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void setBoat(Boat boat) {
        this.boat = boat;
    }

    public Boat getBoat() {
        return boat;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

}
```

Boat Entity

```
@Entity
public class Boat extends AbstractEntity {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "boat", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Rower> rowers = new LinkedList<>();

    public Boat() {
    }

    public Boat(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Rower> getRowers() {
        return rowers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use *rowerRepository* to save a Boat?

```
if (rowerRepository.count() == 0) {
            //Below line is where the error is coming from
            rowerRepository.saveAll(Stream.of("Varsity 8", "Frosh 4+", "JV 8", "Lightweight 2-").map(Boat::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }
```

You should use *boatRepository* instead.

Comment: changed rowerRepository to boatRepository, got this error ```Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction``` Debugged it and it seems to be crashing at the second if statement, at the rowerRepo.saveAll(Stream.of(....

Comment: You should use try-catch exception for the method populateTestData and print out the stack trace to get more detail about the exception.
Base on that, you will know what caused the exception.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're saving `Boat` entities using the `RowerRepository`

```
rowerRepository.saveAll(Stream.of("Varsity 8", "Frosh 4+", "JV 8", "Lightweight 2-")
  .map(Boat::new) // Instantiating Boat entities
  .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Use `boatRepository` instead of `rowerRepository`.